# If $f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$, how can I prove/disprove $f\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) = \Theta(g(n))?$

Tags: functions, asymptotics

To me it looks like there can always be values of constants c1, c2, n0 such that
$$
c_1 \cdot g(n) \leq f\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) \leq c_2 \cdot g(n)
$$

Is there a way to disprove it with a counterexample?

I thought of
$$
g(n) = f(n) = 2^n \\
c_1 \cdot 2^n \leq 2^{\frac{n}{2}} \leq c_2 \cdot 2^n
$$

But can't we choose any values of c1 and c2 to always satisfy the condition?

Comment: There are no fixed positive constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ which make your last inequality work for all $n$ large enough.

Comment: @LeeFisher Thanks for the clarification. Is it okay to derive 2^(n/2) c₁  ≤ 1 ≤ 2^(n/2) c₂  from the inequality and then lead to a contradiction (n can't be a negative integer) as a proof for that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a good counterexample.  If $c_1 \cdot 2^n \le 2^{n/2}$ for all large enough $n$, then
$$
c_1 \le \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{n/2}}{2^n} =\lim_{n\to\infty} 2^{-n/2} = 0
$$
so $c_1 = 0$, which is not allowed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I were to do this without limit, would it be fine if I derive 2^(n/2) c₁ ≤ 1 ≤ 2^(n/2) c₂ from the inequality and then lead to a contradiction (eg - n can't be a negative integer) as a proof for that?

Comment: Well, now do you know $2^{n/2} c_1 \le 1$ is bad?  Especially if $c_1$ is very small? ... Answer: using the limit as $n \to \infty$.